# How to get one dimensional array from reshape command?

Tags: python-2.7

I want to reshape the input to get one dimensional vector. Following command is giving me one row and 9 columns but i want to get 9 rows.Can someone please tell me how i can do that?
    `input= tf.range(0,9)
r1= tf.reshape(input, [9])`

Comment: Provide more context. What is this `tf`? What module are you using for `reshape()`?

Comment: I'm using tensor flow that's why I use tf. I want to do this reshaping by using tensorflow reshape.